# Expression SFINAE and hard errors in c++

Tags: c++, c++20, sfinae

I'm confused about why one of these functions gives a hard error, and the other does not:

```
#include <utility>

template <typename ...Args>
auto ffExists1()
-> decltype(ff(std::declval<Args>()...)); // Attempts to see
    // whether you can call ff (which is not defined or declared)
    // with arguments of type Args... This works fine.

template <typename ...Args>
auto ffExists2() -> decltype(&ff); // Gives me a hard error : ff not defined
```

Why is that?
Also, how do I make `ffExists2` work? Taking a pointer to a function would let me determine the exact signature of `ff` while `ffExists1` only finds out if I can call `ff` with arguments of type `Args...`.

EDIT: here is a version where `ffExists2` depends on a template, causing the same result:

```
#include <utility>

template <typename ...Args>
auto ffExists() -> decltype(ff(std::declval<Args>()...)); //Fine

template <typename ... Args>
void SomeHelperFunc(auto (*) (Args...));

template <typename ...Args>
auto ffExists2() -> decltype(SomeHelperFunc<Args...>(&ff)); // Hard Error
```

Comment: Only expressions that depends on a template parameter can lead to SFINAE. `decltype(&ff)` can be evaluated before instatiation and since it does not exist, it's a hard error.

Comment: @super Yeah but that's the case with ffExists1() too right? As ff is not defined or declared at all... No need for any templates to be instantiated...

Comment: No. In order to evaluate `decltype(ff(std::declval<Args>()...))` properly, the compiler needs to know what `Args` are. The same can't be said for `decltype(&ff)`.

Comment: You are missing the point. `&ff` does still not depend on a template parameter in your updated expression.

Comment: @super How do I make it depend on a template parameter?

Comment: You can't, really. If the intention is to take the address of a non-template free-function. Either it exists and is visible, or it doesn't. It's probably better to write a question where you focus on what you want to achieve with you template functions.

Comment: There is a good chance that what you want to achieve can be done fairly easily, just in a different way then you're thinking.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In `ffExists2`, `ff` doesn't depend on template parameters, thus the lookup for it (i.e. finding the function by the provided name) is done at phase one of [two-phase lookup](https://blog.llvm.org/2009/12/dreaded-two-phase-name-lookup.html), i.e. when the compiler first sees the template, as opposed to when the template arguments are substituted into it.

Because of this, even if `ff` was defined after this template, it wouldn't matter because phase one [is already done by that point](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/unqualified_lookup#Template_definition).

On the other hand, in `ffExists1`, lookup of `ff` depends on the template parameter (because [ADL](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/adl) is a part of this lookup, and ADL requires knowing the types of the parameters, i.e. `Args...`), so the lookup for it is postponed to phase two, i.e. to the point of instantiation of the template,

> at which time ADL examines function declarations that are visible from the template definition context as well as in the template instantiation context, while non-ADL lookup only examines function declarations that are visible from the template definition context (in other words, adding a new function declaration after template definition does not make it visible except via ADL).
>
> — (c) [cppreference](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/unqualified_lookup#Template_definition)

There's no way to make `&ff` depend on a template parameter, and it's impossible to peform SFINAE checks on things that don't depend on template parameters. Any attempt at it would be thwarted by:

> #### [`[temp.res.general]/6.1`](http://eel.is/c++draft/temp#res.general-6.1)
>
> The program is ill-formed, no diagnostic required, if:
>
> — no valid specialization can be generated for a template ...

---

You'd think that C++20 `requires` could help, since you could use it without any templates, but alas:

> #### [`[expr.prim.req.general]/5`](http://eel.is/c++draft/expr.prim.req#general-5)
>
> ...
>
> [Note 1: If a requires-expression contains invalid types or expressions in its requirements, and it does not appear within the declaration of a templated entity, then the program is ill-formed.
> — end note]
>
> If the substitution of template arguments into a requirement would
> always result in a substitution failure, the program is ill-formed; no
> diagnostic required.

Comment: So is ffExists1 not failing portable and conforming to the standard?

Comment: @SomeProgrammer Yes, `ffExists1` is fine. Though keep in mind that the overloads of `ff` that are defined *after* `ffExists1` will only be detected if they can be found via ADL.